# Python requests 403 on post

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to logging on this [site](https://www.avito.ru/profile/login). I always have 403 error.

**code:**

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36'}
login = 'email'
password = 'my_pass'
url_login = 'https://www.avito.ru/profile/'
r = session.post(url_login, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True, verify=True, auth=(login, password))
or
r = requests.post(url_login, data={'login':login, 'password': password}, auth=(login, password), allow_redirects=True, headers=headers,)


print r.status_code
```

or everything from [here](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) returns 403. Whats the problem? Yes, I can use cookies from browser, but I want to understand, why this code wrong. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Cos you want to be sending the POST request to `/profile/login` instead?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're trying to post to `/profile`, while the login form action is `/profile/login`.

Second, you're sending your credentials in both the form `data` and the `auth` parameters. The `auth` is for HTTP Basic authentication and it's probably not what you want. There's no need for that.

Third, keep in mind that error `403 Forbidden` is not the same as `401 Unauthorized`. 403 means the server is refusing to respond it and authentication won't make a difference. Sure, there's a chance whoever implemented it doesn't know the difference, but it's also likely that they are tracking something else and trying to prevent automated access like you're trying to do.